# Is it possible to retrieve the payload from a mutation completion callback in graphQL?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

Using `React`, `react-apollo`, I have a mutation that send a bunch of values to the server, and the server returns `OK` or `NOT OK`.

I would like to update the values only if the operation, but for this, I need to access the payload in the `OnComplete` callback.

ex :

```
  const [updateCardRate] = useMutation<UpdateInfluencerRateCard, UpdateInfluencerRateCardVariables>(UPDATE_CARD_RATE, {
    onCompleted: (e) => {
      // Can I have the variables (not just the response) here ? 
    },
  });


  const handlePriceChange = async (socialAccountType: SocialMediaTypeForRateCard, price: number) => {
    await updateCardRate({ variables: { input: { price, socialAccountType } } });
  };

  return (<button onClick(SocialMediaTypeForRateCard.FACEBOOK, 122) />
```

It looks like it isn't possible without some "tricky" way like using a state ?

EDIT : Tried with state, but doesn't work, the state is null :

```
  const [getPayload, setPayload] = useState<any>(null);
  const [prices, setPrices] = useState<any>(priceCards);

  const [updateCardRate] = useMutation<UpdateInfluencerRateCard, UpdateInfluencerRateCardVariables>(UPDATE_CARD_RATE, {
    onError: useCallback((error: ApolloError) => {
      enqueueSnackbar(t(error.message || 'UnexpectedError'), { variant: 'error' });
      setPrices(priceCards);
    }, []),
    onCompleted: useCallback(() => {
      console.log(getPayload); // this is null
    }, []),
  });

  const handlePriceChange = (socialAccountType: SocialMediaTypeForRateCard, price: number) => {
    setPayload({ price, socialAccountType }); // but it s set here
    updateCardRate({
      variables: { input: { price, socialAccountType } },
    });
  };
```

Comment: `onCompleted` callback does not provide `variables` as parameter. So, I guess, a simple state that stores your variables object should do the job.

Comment: I tried that, but when I store the state, then use it in OnComplete, the state is still set as the previous value, cause I guess the component isn't update suring the call/response.

Comment: btw, I am using `onCompleted: useCallback(() => { }, []),`

Comment: 1. You do not need `async`, `await` on `handlePriceChange`, 2. Even if you do so, you need to set state before you call the mutation

Comment: If you are using callback, make sure the state a dependency of it.

Comment: @Nishant thanks for the reply, please check the edit. thank you

Comment: @Nishant oh ok you right, I am stupid ahah. Please make a comment, I will add you as solution, or will post Myself later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not need to used `async`, `await` on `handlePriceChange`
2. Even if you do so, you need to set state before you call the mutation
3. As you mentioned in your comment, if you are using `useCallback`, make sure that state is a part of dependency list.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to have the variables in the `onCompleted` callback, is to call it when you call the function. Something like this:

```
const [updateCardRate] = useMutation<UpdateInfluencerRateCard, UpdateInfluencerRateCardVariables>(UPDATE_CARD_RATE);

const handlePriceChange = (socialAccountType: SocialMediaTypeForRateCard, price: number ) => {
   updateCardRate({
      variables: { input: { price, socialAccountType } },
      onCompleted: () => {
          // you have the variables here to do whatever you want with them
      }
   });
};
```

Note that I removed the `onCompleted` from the `useMutation` definition, and also the async await clauses from `handlePriceChange`.